# What is the name of the property $a*b/c=a/c*b$?

Tags: terminology

I  know $a*b=b*a$ is called commutative, $a*(b*c) = (a*b)*c$  is associative. What about $a*b/c=a/c*b$?

Comment: Write it (by definition of $/$) as $a*b*c^{-1}=a*c^{-1}*b$;  it is the commutative property.

Comment: More importantly, it's the associative property, @GEdgar.

Answer (score 2):

This is the associative property (and perhaps the commutative property as well, if you worry that $\dfrac bc = \dfrac1c\cdot b = b\cdot\dfrac1c$). You have
$$a\cdot\frac bc = a\cdot\left(\frac1c\cdot b\right) = (a\cdot\frac1c)\cdot b =\frac ac \cdot b.$$